# Converting US mortgage rates to Canadian rates

Tags: exponential-function

Canadian mortgage rates are different from US rates.  Canadian rates are compounded semi-anually.  So a rate of 6% apparently would be 6.09% in practice.

<s>What is the formula for converting a US rate to Canadian rate?  I [came across a formula here](http://www.yorku.ca/amarshal/mortgage.htm) but it doesn't help since I don't know how to get `RM` in the formula.</s>

Rewording question - I need to find the formula for monthly mortgage payments.  The [normal formula](https://i.gyazo.com/4b1002d88514a2687042c8c6b9ee1a0b.png) finds US monthly payments.  What would be the formula to find Canadian monthly payments?

Comment: What are the rules for US rates?

Comment: In the US the rates are applied monthly.  Canada they are applied semi-annually.  (US mortgages are always slightly more expensive) @PiyushDivyanakar

Comment: $r_m$ is the monthly rate which is equal to annual rate divided by 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is how to convert a nominal annual rate, compounded semi-annually, to a nominal annual rate, compounded monthly.  A nominal annual rate compounded $n$ times a year is usually designated $r^{(n)}.$  The equivalent effective rate $r$ is given by $$
\left(1+\frac{r^{(n)}}{n}\right)^n=1+r
$$
The formula gets a bit complicated, so let me do an example.  Suppose you are quoted a Canadian rate of $8\%$.  The effective annual rate is given by $$\left(1+\frac{.08}{2}\right)^2=1+r\implies r =.0816$$

Now we have to find the equivalent monthly rate: $$
\left(1+\frac{r^{(12)}}{12}\right)^{12}=1.0816\implies r^{(12)}=12\left(\sqrt[12]{1.0816}-1\right)\approx .078698$$

The equivalent U.S. rate is about $7.87\%$

**EDIT** Just in case I haven't made myself clear, what I'm calling the "effective annual rate" is what the U.S. truth-in-lending law calls the "annual percentage rate" (APR).

**EDIT** To get the monthly payments, use the formula you linked, with $n=$ the total monthly payments. (For a $30$ year loan, $n$ is $360$). The $r$ to use in that formula should be the nominal monthly rate that I called $r^{(12)}$ divided by $12$.  So in the example above, we would have $$r = \frac{.078698}{12}\approx .006558$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Your answer seems to show that effective US rates are cheaper (US 7.87% vs Canadian 8.16%), but actually Canadian payments are lower for the same rate.  [Canadian example](https://i.gyazo.com/68909bf209837864c7f4163b589d2974.png) vs [US example](https://i.gyazo.com/970b091333ed92c99960aa39b2d7ea60.png).  How does that work?

Comment: When I use the [normal mortgage formula](https://i.gyazo.com/4b1002d88514a2687042c8c6b9ee1a0b.png), I get the US monthly payments.  I apologize for my poorly worded question, my main question is what is the correct formula to find Canadian monthly mortgage payments.

Comment: No.  The effective rate is $8.16\%$ in both cases.  The U.S. rate just sounds cheaper because it's quoted monthly.  The APR gives the true annual rate.  To get the payments, use the same formula, but set $n=2$ instead of $12$.

Comment: Sorry set `n=2` for which formula?  The formula you provided or the normal mortgage formula I linked?  I tried both and I don't seem to be getting the right value

Comment: I beg your pardon.  I was wrong about getting the payments.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes I got it!  I was stuck for awhile because I was confused at the $r^(12)$.  I thouught I had to do $0.816^12$.  Then I realized $r^(12)$ was not related to $r$ at all.  Figuring out stuff after that was easy.  Thanks for your time!